# Find min / max value in Swift Array

Tags: arrays, swift

Given an array of Swift numeric values, how can I find the minimum and maximum values?

I've so far got a simple (but potentially expensive) way:

```
var myMax = sort(myArray,>)[0]
```

And how I was taught to do it at school:

```
var myMax = 0
for i in 0..myArray.count {
    if (myArray[i] > myMax){myMax = myArray[i]}
}
```

Is there a better way to get the minimum or maximum value from an integer Array in Swift? Ideally something that's one line such as Ruby's `.min` and `.max`.

Comment: Other answers explained how to get one. [Now we can get both at once](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/MinMax.md).

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Given:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Swift 3:

```
numbers.min() // equals 1
numbers.max() // equals 5
```

Swift 2:

```
numbers.minElement() // equals 1
numbers.maxElement() // equals 5
```

Comment: Works only on `Comparable` objects, so `NSDecimalNumber` won't work for example.

Comment: If your array is empty this returns 0: `nums.min() ?? 0 `

Comment: and if you have an array of `[Int?]` just put a `.flatMap{ $0 }.max()` inbetween :)

Answer (score 109):

To calculate an array's min and max values yourself, you can use `reduce`. This was a key solution prior to `.min()` and `.max()` appearing in Swift.

---

Use the almighty `reduce`:

```
let nums = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 6];
let numMax = nums.reduce(Int.min, { max($0, $1) })
```

Similarly:

```
let numMin = nums.reduce(Int.max, { min($0, $1) })
```

`reduce` takes a first value that is the initial value for an internal accumulator variable, then applies the passed function (here, it's anonymous) to the accumulator and each element of the array successively, and stores the new value in the accumulator. The last accumulator value is then returned.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. There's a lot that's not in the iBook it seems!

Comment: Those are just general functional programming techniques, they're not specific to Swift.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet you can actually simplify this to just: `nums.reduce(Int.min, max)` since `max`'s prototype already matches the type that `reduce` is expecting

Comment: is there a reason why this does not work with arrays of doubles?

Comment: You'd probably have to change the `Int.max` part.

Comment: The min/max function signatures match the combine: parameter signature so you can just pass the function itself: `let numMax = nums.reduce(Int.min, combine: max)`

Answer (score 55):

With Swift 5, `Array`, like other `Sequence` Protocol conforming objects (`Dictionary`, `Set`, etc), has two methods called `max()` and `max(by:)` that return the maximum element in the sequence or `nil` if the sequence is empty.

---

## #1. Using `Array`'s `max()` method

If the element type inside your sequence conforms to `Comparable` protocol (may it be `String`, `Float`, `Character` or one of your custom class or struct), you will be able to use `max()` that has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688806-max):

```
@warn_unqualified_access func max() -> Element?
```

> Returns the maximum element in the sequence.

The following Playground codes show to use `max()`:

```
let intMax = [12, 15, 6].max()
let stringMax = ["bike", "car", "boat"].max()

print(String(describing: intMax)) // prints: Optional(15)
print(String(describing: stringMax)) // prints: Optional("car")
```

```
class Route: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let distance: Int
    var description: String { return "Route with distance: \(distance)" }

    init(distance: Int) {
        self.distance = distance
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distance == rhs.distance
    }

    static func <(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
    }

}

let routes = [
    Route(distance: 20),
    Route(distance: 30),
    Route(distance: 10)
]

let maxRoute = routes.max()
print(String(describing: maxRoute)) // prints: Optional(Route with distance: 30)
```

---

## #2. Using `Array`'s `max(by:)` method

If the element type inside your sequence does not conform to `Comparable` protocol, you will have to use `max(by:)` that has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294243-max):

```
@warn_unqualified_access func max(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?
```

> Returns the maximum element in the sequence, using the given predicate as the comparison between elements.

The following Playground codes show to use `max(by:)`:

```
let dictionary = ["Boat" : 15, "Car" : 20, "Bike" : 40]

let keyMaxElement = dictionary.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.key < b.key
})

let valueMaxElement = dictionary.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.value < b.value
})

print(String(describing: keyMaxElement)) // prints: Optional(("Car", 20))
print(String(describing: valueMaxElement)) // prints: Optional(("Bike", 40))
```

```
class Route: CustomStringConvertible {

    let distance: Int
    var description: String { return "Route with distance: \(distance)" }

    init(distance: Int) {
        self.distance = distance
    }

}

let routes = [
    Route(distance: 20),
    Route(distance: 30),
    Route(distance: 10)
]

let maxRoute = routes.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.distance < b.distance
})

print(String(describing: maxRoute)) // prints: Optional(Route with distance: 30)
```

Comment: In Swift 3 "maxElement" has been renamed to "max"

Answer (score 17):

The other answers are all correct, but don't forget you could also use collection operators, as follows:

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var max: Int = (list as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@max.self") as Int
```

you can also find the average in the same way:

```
var avg: Double = (list as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@avg.self") as Double
```

This syntax might be less clear than some of the other solutions, but it's interesting to see that `-valueForKeyPath:` can still be used :)

Answer (score 12):

You can use with `reduce`:

```
let randomNumbers = [4, 7, 1, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9]
let maxNumber = randomNumbers.reduce(randomNumbers[0]) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 } //result is 9
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0**

You can try this code programmatically.

```
func getSmallAndGreatestNumber() -> Void {

    let numbers = [145, 206, 116, 809, 540, 176]
    var i = 0
    var largest = numbers[0]
    var small = numbers[0]
    while i < numbers.count{

        if (numbers[i] > largest) {
            largest = numbers[i]
        }
        if (numbers[i] < small) {
            small = numbers[i]
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
    print("Maximum Number ====================\(largest)")// 809
    print("Minimum Number ====================\(small)")// 116
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With Swift 1.2 (and maybe earlier) you now need to use:

```
let nums = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 6];
let numMax = nums.reduce(Int.min, combine: { max($0, $1) })
```

For working with Double values I used something like this:

```
let nums = [1.3, 6.2, 3.6, 9.7, 4.9, 6.3];
let numMax = nums.reduce(-Double.infinity, combine: { max($0, $1) })
```

Comment: You could also just do this `let numMax = nums.reduce(-Double.infinity, combine: max)`, the max function signature matches the combine: parameter signature.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2.0, the `minElement` and `maxElement` become methods of `SequenceType` protocol, you should call them like:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
print(a.maxElement()) //3
print(a.minElement()) //1
```

Using `maxElement` as a function like **`maxElement(a)`** is **unavailable** now.

The syntax of Swift is in flux, so I can just confirm this in **Xcode version7 beta6**.

It may be modified in the future, so I suggest that you'd better check the doc before you use these methods.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a performance test for the solutions posted here. https://github.com/tedgonzalez/MaxElementInCollectionPerformance

This is the fastest for **Swift 5**

`array.max()`

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 7, 5];    
var val = sort(numbers){$0 > $1}[0];
```

Comment: To me this looks much like `var myMax = sort(myArray,>)[0]`

Comment: Sort has too much overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) introduced 2021 contains [`Minima and/or Maxima`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/MinMax.md) which is likely highly optimized.

Example from the documentation:

```
let numbers = [7, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 9]
if let (smallest, largest) = numbers.minAndMax(by: <) {
    // Work with 1 and 9....
}
```

> *The total complexity is O(k log k + nk), which will result in a runtime close to O(n) if k is a small amount. If k is a large amount (more than 10% of the collection), we fall back to sorting the entire array. Realistically, this means the worst case is actually O(n log n).*

Answer (score 0):

> Updated for Swift 3/4:

Use below simple lines of code to find the max from array;

```
var num = [11, 2, 7, 5, 21]
var result = num.sorted(){
    $0 > $1
}
print("max from result: \(result[0])") // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious why you think the way it was taught in school is potentially expensive? You're running a for loop which has the time complexity of O(N). That's actually better than most sorting algorithms and equivalent to the performance of higher-order methods like `reduce`.

So I would think that in terms of performance, a for loop is as good as it gets. I don't think you'll find anything better than O(N) for finding max.

Of course, just use the `.max()` method provided by apple is the way to go.

Comment: I'm referring to the one using sort when talking about the expensive one.

Answer (score 0):

If **both** minimum and maximum values are desired, an efficient approach could be to use a single `reduce` operation with a tuple:

```
let values = [11, 2, 7, 5, 21]

let (minimum, maximum) = values.reduce((Int.max, Int.min)) {
    (min($0.0, $1), max($0.1, $1))
}

print(minimum, maximum) // 2, 21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array: [Int] = [2, -22, -1, -5600, 333, -167]
var min = 0
var max = array[0]

for i in array {
    // finding the min
    if min > i {
        min = i
    }
    // finding the max
    if max < i {
        max = i
    }
}

print("Minimum: \(min)\nMaximum: \(max)")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also sort your array and then use `array.first` or `array.last`

Comment: This is computationally slower. You can find the max in linear time.

Comment: I'm a very new @CharlieEgan, can you explain linear time or point me to a tutorial. Thanks a lot

Comment: do some reading around 'time complexity' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). This is also worth a read: http://bigocheatsheet.com. Some good worked examples here: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms