# Swift equivalent for MIN and MAX macros

Tags: generics, swift

In C / Objective-C it is possible to find the minimum and maximum value between two numbers using MIN and MAX macros. Swift doesn't support macros and it seems that there are no equivalents in the language / base library. Should one go with a custom solution, maybe based on generics like this [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`min` and `max` are defined in Swift:

```
func max<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
func min<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
```

and used like so:

```
let min = min(1, 2)
let max = max(1, 2)
```

See this great writeup on [documented & undocumented built-in functions in Swift](https://github.com/chenee/swift-74-functions).

Comment: Sorry.  How did you learn this?  I don't see it in 'The Swift Programming Language' nor in an Xcode6 documentation search.

Comment: @GoZoner Sometimes you just have to type it up in Xcode and check out the Swift header. If you type `let a : Int = 5` and Command + Click on `Int`, you get to see cool stuff!

Comment: Wow, glad I asked!  At best I had been typing `a.` and scrolling through the Xcode completion possibilities... but 'Command + Click' is the ticket!

Comment: @GoZoner Autocomplete is a great place to search too! Unfortunately, its very wonky for Xcode 6 at the moment...

Comment: @GoZoner https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs3minuRxs10ComparablerFTxx_x

Comment: The code snippet contains a lot of noise  
( <T : Comparable> ?  rest: T... ? What do those mean?) and doesn't really explain how to use the function.  It'd be much more helpful to have a line of code actually showing its use.

Answer (score 39):

As pointed out, Swift provides `max` and `min` functions.

An example (updated for Swift 2.x).

```
let numbers = [ 1, 42, 5, 21 ]
var maxNumber = Int()

for number in numbers {
    maxNumber = max(maxNumber, number as Int)
}

print("the max number is \(maxNumber)")   // will be 42
```

Comment: Int() has the value of 0 so if your numbers are negative this won't work

Comment: you could make the maxNumber optional and replace the for loop with this: numbers.forEach{maxNumber = maxNumber != nil ? max(maxNumber!,$0) : $0}

Answer (score 25):

With Swift 5, [`max(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538951-max) and [`min(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538339-min) are part of the [Global Numeric Functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/global_numeric_functions). `max(_:_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func max<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T where T : Comparable
```

You can use it like this with `Int`s:

```
let maxInt = max(5, 12) // returns 12
```

---

Also note that there are other functions called [`max(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541407-max) and [`min(_:_:_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1540516-min) that allows you to compare even more parameters. `max(_:_:_:_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func max<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T, _ z: T, _ rest: T...) -> T where T : Comparable
```

You can use it like this with `Float`s:

```
let maxInt = max(12.0, 18.5, 21, 26, 32.9, 19.1) // returns 32.9
```

---

With Swift however, you're not limited to use `max(_:_:)` and its siblings with numbers. In fact, those functions are generic and can accept any parameter type that conforms to `Comparable` protocol, may it be `String`, `Character` or one of your custom `class` or `struct`.

Thereby, the following Playground sample code works perfectly:

```swift
class Route: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {

    let distance: Int
    var description: String {
        return "Route with distance: \(distance)"
    }

    init(distance: Int) {
        self.distance = distance
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distance == rhs.distance
    }

    static func <(lhs: Route, rhs: Route) -> Bool {
        return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
    }

}

let route1 = Route(distance: 4)
let route2 = Route(distance: 8)

let maxRoute = max(route1, route2)
print(maxRoute) // prints "Route with distance: 8"
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to get the min/max element of elements that are inside an `Array`, a `Set`, a `Dictionary` or any other sequence of `Comparable` elements, you can use the [max()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641492-max) or the [min()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641174-min) methods (see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956323/1966109) for more details).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Much better than the answer above since you actually give an example of usage, rather than a cryptic header.

Answer (score 15):

**SWIFT 4**
Syntax changed a bit:

```
public func max<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T where T : Comparable
public func min<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T where T : Comparable
```

and

```
public func max<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T, _ z: T, _ rest: T...) -> T where T : Comparable
public func min<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T, _ z: T, _ rest: T...) -> T where T : Comparable
```

So when you use it you should write like in this example:

```
let min = 0
let max = 100
let value = -1000

let currentValue = Swift.min(Swift.max(min, value), max)
```

So you get the value from 0 to 100 don't matter if is it below 0 or higher 100.

Comment: If you're getting a fun compiler error in XCode 9 like me, saying that max() doesn't exist even when you clearly pass it two `Int`s, then change it to Swift.max and suddenly yay, things are better. Thanks wm.p1us!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let numbers = [2, 3, 10, 9, 14, 6]
let min = numbers.min()
let max = numbers.max()
print("Max = \(max) Min = \(min)")
```