# "cannot call value of non-function type" error when attempting to call the max(_:_:) function

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to call the max function: `max(x: T, y: T)`. However I keep getting the following error when I type `max(2,3)`:

> > error: cannot call value of non-function type `Int`
> >     var a = max(2, 3)

I am a beginner, and I have never encountered a function signature that uses a type "`T`". SO threads relating to using the max function call it in the manner I am (like `max(2,3)` ) so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I am looking for an explanation on the "`T`" and how to call functions that support generic types and how to make the `max` function return 3 when comparing integers 2 and 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33938397/2757916 a SO answer showing min/max usage like `max(2,3)`

Comment: Sounds like you have defined a variable named `max`, causing a naming conflict with the function `max`. Although without seeing your code, it's hard to say.

Comment: OMG... wth... you are absolutely correct. I finally understand what the error message is telling me...

Comment: @Hamish Please post your comment as an answer so this question can be closed

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Hmm... at the time, I voted to close this question as a "simple typographical error" due to the fact that it was lacking an MCVE & appropriate title for the actual problem (this has nothing to do with generics), therefore I doubted it would be of much use to any future searchers. However, if it isn't going to get closed, I agree that posting an answer (& editing the title) would be the best thing to do – I have gone ahead and done this.

Comment: @Hamish It definitely is such a case, but to be honest, it seems like this would be a fairly common mistake. `min` and `max` are common variable names. I can imagine this happening to others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem (as [you've confirmed in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808729/how-to-call-functions-that-support-generic-types-min-max-functions-example#comment64985736_38808729)) is that you have defined a variable named `max`, causing a naming conflict with the function [`max(_:_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/max/#func-max-t_-comparable_-t_-t).

The solution therefore is to either specify the `Swift` module namespace (as [George suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808796/2976878)) in order to disambiguate the fact that you're referring to the [`max(_:_:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/max/#func-max-t_-comparable_-t_-t) function:

```
Swift.max(2, 3)
```

Or, preferably, you should consider renaming your variable. I strongly suspect that there's a more descriptive name you could give it (remember, [the Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) favours clarity over brevity).

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling max within extension Int?

Try Swift.max(2, 3).

Comment: Hi George, as explained by Hamish in the comments above, I had a predefined variable named max which was causing a conflict. Thanks for your help.