# Max and min in an array of Float in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036514/correct-way-to-find-max-in-an-array-in-swift), to obtain the maximum of an array we can do:

```
let nums = [1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 6];
let numMax = nums.reduce(Int.min, { max($0, $1) })
```

How can we do the same for an `Array<Float>`, since there's no `min` and `max` for `Float`?

```
let floats: Array<Float> = [2.45, 7.21, 1.35, 10.22, 2.45, 3];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161004/1187415 works for 
for all sequences of comparable elements, therefore also for an array of floats:

```
let floats: Array<Float> = [2.45, 7.21, 1.35, 10.22, 2.45, 3]
let numMax = maxElement(floats)
```

---

`maxElement()` is defined in the Swift library as

```
/// Returns the maximum element in `elements`.  Requires:
/// `elements` is non-empty. O(countElements(elements))
func maxElement<R : SequenceType where R.Generator.Element : Comparable>(elements: R) -> R.Generator.Element
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use the first array element as the initial value:

```
let numMax = floats.reduce(floats[0], { max($0, $1) })
```

but of course you need to check that the `floats` array is not empty before doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-FLT_MAX` which returns minimum magnitude of `Float` and used for same purpose

```
let numMax = floats.reduce(-FLT_MAX, { max($0, $1) })
```

For `Double` array you can use `-DBL_MAX`

If you want maximum magnitude value of `Float` use `FLT_MAX`.`FLT_MIN` is Minimum representable postive floating-point number.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `FLT_MIN`.

Comment: It should be `-FLT_MAX` that for minimum magnitude value for `Float`.FLT_MIN gives minimum vale of exponent.So i am changing my answer

Comment: Where can I find the documentation of those variables?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 has a `.max()` method for `Array<Float>`.

Example:

```
let floats: Array<Float> = [2.45, 7.21, 1.35, 10.22, 2.45, 3]
let max = floats.max()
```

Note: `max()` returns an optional so there's a chance it could come back nil.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2:

```
var graphPoints:[Int] = [4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3]
let maxValue = graphPoints.maxElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Swift >= 5.0

```
let numbers = [12.9, 2.7, 3.7, 4, 5, 4, 12.8]
print(numbers.max() ?? 0) // Output 12.9
print(numbers.min() ?? 0) // Output 2.7
```