# How to find the max value in a Swift object array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Let say I got an array with `Usr` objects. And the `Usr` object have the attribute `age`. Except from reading the `Usr`object one by one, and compare the `age` value one by one, is there any shortcuts to do so? Thx.

Comment: Maybe by using (from Objective-C, but there may be a Swift equivalent) `[yourArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.age"];` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to find max in an Array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036514/correct-way-to-find-max-in-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply map users array to array of user's age and the find max age:

```
class Usr {
    var age: Int

    init(_ age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}

let users = [Usr(1), Usr(8), Usr(5)]

let maxAge = maxElement(users.map{$0.age}) // 8
```

Comment: Please note the new syntax for Swift 3: let maxAge = users.map { $0.age }.maxElement()

Comment: Use max() instead of maxElement() in Swift 3.

Comment: Isn't max() for comparing 2 values as in: let x = max(2, 4)? The compiler will only accept arrayOfInts.maxElement().

Comment: In Swift 3 you must use `arrayOfInts.max()` in Swift 2 `arrayOfInts.maxElement()`. `max()` is variadic for 2 or more values.

Answer (score 39):

```
struct User {
    var age: Int
}

let users = [ User(age: 10), User(age: 20), User(age: 30)]
let oldestUser = users.max { $0.age < $1.age }
oldestUser?.age  // 30
```

Comment: @toing_toing Why? `map` alone returns an array of elements with a given transformation applied to them. `max(by:)` finds the maximum element in the sequence with a given predicate.

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 3:**

```
let users = [Usr(15), Usr(25), Usr(20)]
let max = users.map { $0.age }.max()
```

> // max = 25

Answer (score 6):

Use **max(by:)** function

```
class Usr {
   var age: Int
   init(_ age: Int) {
       self.age = age
   }
}

let users = [Usr(3), Usr(8), Usr(6)]
if let userWithMaxAge : Usr = users.max(by: {$0.age < $1.age}){
    print(userWithMaxAge.age)
}
```

It will print 8

Answer (score 6):

The previous answers are a little mixed and don't exactly describe what I will achieve with the respecting approach. So, there are two different approaches, based on what you want.

If this is your model:

```
struct Purchase {
   let id: String
   let amount: Double
}
```

And these are your objects:

```
let iPhonePurchase = Purchase(id: "iPhone", amount: 999.00)
let iPadPurchase = Purchase(id: "iPad", amount: 1299.00)
let purchases = [iPhonePurchase, iPadPurchase]
```

If you want the object itself containing the highest value, use:

```
let highestPurchase = purchases.max { $0.amount < $1.amount }
```

This returns the object for `iPadPurchase`.

On the other hand, if you don't want to get the whole object, just the highest amount value:

```
let highestPurchase = purchases.map { $0.amount }.max()
```

Here you get `1299.00` as the highest value.

Answer (score 5):

Other way:

```
class Usr {
    var age: Int
    init(_ age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}

let users = [Usr(1), Usr(8), Usr(5)]
let largestAge = users.map{ $0.age }.reduce(0) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 } // 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way in Swift 3:

```
let users = [Usr(1), Usr(8), Usr(5)]    
let maxAge = users.map { $0.age }.max()
print(maxAge ?? "No users") // Optional(8)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let array1 = [75,37,45,80,75,24,65,97,60,83]
var smallvalue = 0
        
for countindex in 0..<array1.count {
  let index1 = array1[countindex]
            
  if countindex == 0 {
    let index2 = array1[countindex + 1]
    if index1 < index2 {
      smallvalue = index1
    } else {
      smallvalue = index2
    }
  } else {
    if smallvalue > index1 {
      smallvalue = index1
    }
  }
}
print(smallvalue) //print 24
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: a lot of errors - separate check for a first element in each loop cycle, app will fail if you have an array with 0 or 1 element and etc

Answer (score -4):

```
var studentsAndScores = ["Amy": Int(readLine()!)!, "James": Int(readLine()!)!, "Helen": Int(readLine()!)!]

func highestScore(scores: [String: Int]) {

  let a = studentsAndScores["Amy"]!
  let b = studentsAndScores["James"]!
  let c = studentsAndScores["Helen"]!

  var temp = 0

  if a > temp {
    temp =  a 
  }
  if b > temp {
    temp = b
  }
  if c > temp {
    temp = c
  }

  print(temp)
}

highestScore(scores: studentsAndScores)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.