# How to return max element in array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Using the example from here [How to find the max value in a Swift object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875778/how-to-find-the-max-value-in-a-swift-object-array), how do you return the `Usr` element rather than the `Int age` value?

```
class Usr {
    var age: Int

    init(_ age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}

let users = [Usr(1), Usr(8), Usr(5)]

let maxAge = users.map{$0.age}.max() //this returns 8 instead of the instance
```

Comment: Use there Comparable protocol on user to make max work. Then you can use `users.max()` and it will return the user you want.

Comment: The `max` function can also take a custom predicate to compare elements – did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41217004/2976878) to the question you linked to? It'll return the `Usr` with the maximum age, or `nil` if the array is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of great ways to do this in Swift. A quick and easy way is to use the `reduce` function:

```
let users = [Usr(1), Usr(8), Usr(5)]

let max: Usr = users.reduce(Usr(Int.min)) {
    ($0.age > $1.age) ? $0 : $1
}

print(max.age) // 8
```

You can also make your `Usr` conform to the `Comparable` protocol and use the `max()` function:

```
extension Usr: Comparable {}

func ==(lhs: Usr, rhs: Usr) -> Bool {
    return lhs.age < rhs.age
}

func <(lhs: Usr, rhs: Usr) -> Bool {
    return lhs.age < rhs.age
}

let maxUser = users.max()
```

Of course you can also use a more traditional loop as well:

```
var maxUser = users[0]
for user in users {
    if user.age > maxUser.age {
        maxUser = user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be shorter options but this is one way:

```
let maxAgeUser = users.reduce(users.first, { $0!.age > $1.age ? $0 : $1 })
```

Comment: You can replace the whole `$0!.age > $1.age ? $0 : $1` with `max($0.age, $1.age)` to make it even shorter. So it would be `let maxAgeUser = users.reduce(users.first, { max($0.age, $1.age) })`