# How to find object with smallest property value in a Swift object array?

Tags: arrays, swift, min

I have the following Object Array for the Place class:

```
class Place: NSObject {
    var distance:Double = Double()
    init(_ distance: Double) {
        self.distance = distance
    }
}


let places = [Place(1.5), Place(8.4), Place(4.5)]
```

I need to get the Place with the minimum distance.
I tried using

```
let leastDistancePlace = places.min { $0.distance > $1.distance }
```

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217004/4858605) answer for a similar question, but it gave the following error.

> Contextual closure type '(Place) -> _' expects 1 argument, but 2 were
> used in closure body

**PS:**

As per @robmayoff 's answer, I tried the following in a playground, but I keep getting an error:

> value of Type [Place] no member min

Please check this screenshot.
[image]

My swift version is : Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)

Comment: You should use `max` or `min` (as in the referenced answer), not `map`

Comment: “it does not work” is not enough information. How does it fail? Do you get a compile-time error? Do you get a run-time error? Does it compile and run but produce the wrong answer? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: Incidentally, in your attempt, you said `places.map` but the answer you linked said `places.max`. Perhaps you meant to say `places.min`?

Comment: Why do you [leave a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875778/how-to-find-the-max-value-in-a-swift-object-array/41217004#comment73101921_41217004) at the referenced answer that "it should be map" and then ask a new question that "map does not work"?

Comment: @MartinR Actually both map and max didnt work. It maybe because I put invalid arguments into the cosure. I clarified it there. Sorry

Comment: @toing_toing: Better clarify your question here, before it is closed :)

Comment: @MartinR added the error I got

Comment: @robmayoff added details, seems issue was with the arguments I used

Comment: @toing_toing: Again: You want `max`, not `map`. That compiles without problems.

Comment: @MartinR edited. I tried `max`, but it says value of Type [Place] no member max

Comment: I have copied your updated code into a new Xcode 8.2.1/Swift 3 project and it compiles (and runs) without problems.

Comment: In Swift 2.2, `min` was called `minElement`.

Answer (score 18):

```
let leastDistancePlace = places.min { $0.distance < $1.distance }
```

or

```
let leastDistancePlace = places.min(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance })
```

Example:

```
:; xcrun swift
"crashlog" and "save_crashlog" command installed, use the "--help" option for detailed help
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1>     class Place { 
  2.         var distance:Double = Double() 
  3.         init(_ distance: Double) { 
  4.             self.distance = distance 
  5.         } 
  6.     } 
  7.  
  8.  
  9.     let places = [Place(1.5), Place(8.4), Place(4.5)] 
 10.     let leastDistancePlace = places.min { $0.distance < $1.distance }
places: [Place] = 3 values {
  [0] = {
    distance = 1.5
  }
  [1] = {
    distance = 8.4000000000000004
  }
  [2] = {
    distance = 4.5
  }
}
leastDistancePlace: Place? = (distance = 1.5) {
  distance = 1.5
}
 11>
```

Comment: please check the updated question. Its quite bizzare. I believe your solution should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @toing_toing, use `minElement` instead of `min` in Swift 2.2.  You really should update to Swift 3 and latest Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

```
let sortedPlaces = places.sorted(by: { $0.distance < $1.distance })
let first = sortedPlace.first
```

just use sort

Comment: If you *only* need the the smallest (or largest) element then max/min is more efficient than sorting the array.

Comment: Or `min(by:)`. O(n) rather than O(nlog(n)).

Comment: oh, my bad, forgot about `min` =)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is poorly worded however I think I know what you are trying to ask. The mapping function is generally used for tranformations:

```
let distances = places.map({ (place: Place) -> Int in
    place.distance
})
```

For shorthand

```
let distances = places.map({ $0.distance })
```

You can then use max or min on this array of integers in order to extract the value you desire.