# Creating a CGRect that encompasses a UIBezierPath and NSArray x Array in the process

Tags: arrays, swift, max, minimum

All I need to do is to create a `CGRect` that encompasses a `UIBezierPath` and I have an array of `CGPoint`.

To create this `CGRect` all I need to do is to enumerate the array of `CGPoint` and find the minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates.

Then I remembered that the old and good `NSArray` had this function called `valueForKeyPath` that could be used in conjunction with something like `valueForKeyPath:@max.x` or `valueForKeyPath:@min.x` that would do the magic to find the minimum and maximum values of x and y.

I am new to Swift. This is the first time I am using Swift to create serious code.

Is there any magic in Swift arrays that can be used to do that, instead of creating complex enumerations and loops?

Comment: You can use collection's max and/or min methods in Swift as well. Btw You should always use native collection when coding in Swift. Array is always preferred over NSArray.

Comment: ok, I know that I should not use NSArray in swift but remember that I have an array of CGPoint, so I cannot use min/max, I guess.

Comment: `if let maxX = points.max(by: { $0.x < $1.x }) {` `print(maxX)` `}`

Comment: @Rob yes, just straight lines. `bounds`... how could I miss that. Thanks. If you make this an answer I will accept that because it is the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution, if you already have the `UIBezierPath`, is to just get its [`bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624350-bounds):

```
let rect = path.bounds
```

---

If you have an array of points and want the bounds of that encompasses those points, you could `min` and `max` the `x` and `y` coordinates, but I might `reduce` the [`union`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455837-union) of all the points:

```
let points = [
    CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200),
    CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300),
    CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400),
    CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300)
]

let rect = points.first.map { firstPoint in
    points.dropFirst()
        .reduce(CGRect(origin: firstPoint, size: .zero)) { rect, point in
            rect.union(CGRect(origin: point, size: .zero))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you still have access to [`value(atKeyPath:)`](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift) in Swift, there is [a more idiomatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949517/1749551) to do this. I also happen to think it's clearer. Save the issue of optionals, of course…

```
let list = [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20),
            CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2),
            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)]
let max = list.map { $0.x }.max()
let min = list.map { $0.x }.min()
print(max, min)

// Output: Optional(100.0) Optional(1.0)
```