# Correct way to find leftmost position in an Array of CGPoints in Swift

Tags: swift, reduce, cgpoint

Drawing from [Correct way to find max in an Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036514/correct-way-to-find-max-in-an-array-in-swift), I am attempting to find the leftmost position in Swift array using `reduce`. I would have thought that this would work:

```
var a = [CGPoint(x:1,y:1),CGPoint(x:2,y:2),CGPoint(x:0,y:0)]
var leftMost = a.reduce(CGPoint(x:CGFloat.max,y:CGFloat.max)) {min($0.x,$1.x)}
```

However, I get this error:

```
`Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'Comparable'
```

Of course, I'm not comparing a CGPoint, I'm comparing the point `.x`, whic should be a `CGFloat`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The array holds `CGPoint`, whereas in the reduce closure you're trying to return a `CGFloat` - you have to convert it to a `CGPoint` instead:

```
var leftMost = a.reduce(CGPoint(x:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude,y:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)) {
    CGPoint(x: min($0.x,$1.x), y: $0.y)
}.x
```

I know, the error message doesn't help much :)

Another way to achieve the same result is by transforming the points into x coordinates first, and then reduce:

```
var leftMost = a.map { $0.x }.reduce(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude) { min($0,$1) }
```

maybe easier to read, although probably more expensive in terms of performance. But as @MartinR suggests, it can also be simplified as:

```
var leftMost = a.reduce(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude) { min($0, $1.x) }
```

Comment: The second solution can also be written as `var leftMost = a.reduce(CGFloat.max) { min($0, $1.x) }` – easy to read *and* performant :)

Comment: @MartinR: today your task is to find simplified versions of my solutions... isn't it? ;-) Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. In fact `var leftMost = a.reduce(CGFloat.max) { min($0, $1.x) }` is what I was looking for.  Both you and @MartinR should share!

Comment: @Antonio: I would not bet on the performance for either of your solutions. I know that such kind of loop is easily recognized and optimized by a compiler ending up with almost similar machine code. Though I can't speak for Swift. If performance counts one should anyway make benchmarks. But in general readability rules.

Comment: This returns min value from array of CGPoint, I also need max X from array of CGPoint, try to get it by using max instead of min, but it didn't work for me.
Can you guys share code for find max X from array of CGPoint?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Anjalijariwala have you replaced `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` with either `CGFloat. leastNonzeroMagnitude ` or `CGFloat. leastNormalMagnitude `?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 implementation:

Usage:

```
let leftMost = self.findPoint(points: points, position: .leftMost)
```

Function and enum:

```
  enum Position {
    case topMost
    case bottomMost
    case leftMost
    case rightMost
  }
  func findPoint(points: [CGPoint], position: Position) -> CGPoint? {
    var result: CGPoint?
    switch (position) {
    case .bottomMost:
      result = points.max { a, b in a.y < b.y }
    case .topMost:
      result = points.max { a, b in a.y > b.y }
    case .leftMost:
      result = points.max { a, b in a.x > b.x }
    case .rightMost:
      result = points.max { a, b in a.x < b.x }
    }
    return result
  }
```