# How to convert NSArray to [Int] with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My question is simple,

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

As I want to find the max value in the string, and I want to use the method in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036514/correct-way-to-find-max-in-an-array-in-swift), so I need to do this:

```
let array = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as [AnyObject]
let numArray = array as! [Int]
let maxNum = numArray.reduce(Int.min, combine: {max($0,$1)})
```

But, there will be an error in "**array as! [Int]**"

```
fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C
```

And if it's

```
let numArray = array as! [String]
```

It will be ok but we cannot use the **reduce** method.

So, how to convert the array with string to [Int]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and optionals, preventing usage of forced unwrapping, which can cause the app to crash if the string doesn't actually contain numbers.

Here's the code:

```
let array = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

let initial: Int? = .None
let max = array.reduce(initial) {
    let num = $1.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).toInt()

    return num > $0 ? num : $0
}
```

The first line splits the string into an array of strings - notice that there's no need of a cast, because the method already returns an array of strings.

The `reduce` method is used by passing an optional integer as initial value, set to `.None` (which is a synonym for `nil`).

The closure passed to `reduce` converts the current value into an integer using `toInt()`, which returns an optional, to account for the string not convertible to a valid integer.

Next, the closure returns the converted number, if it's greater than the value calculated at the previous iteration (or than the initial value), otherwise it returns the value at the last iteration.

Note that comparing integers and nil is perfectly legit: any integer value is *always* greater than `nil` (even a negative value).

This method works with a "normal" list of numbers:

```
let string = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" // The result is 7
```

but also with lists having numbers and non-numbers:

```
let string = "1, 2, three, 4, 5, 6, seven" // the result is 6
```

and with lists containing no numbers:

```
let string = "one, two, three, three, four, five, six, seven" // the result is nil
```

Comment: Optionals are implicitly initialized to `nil`, `= .None` is not needed.

Comment: I change `let initial: Int? = .None` to `let initial: int! = .None` cause I have to get the string, so `return "\(max)"` will have some `optional string`, but `int!` will be OK. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @KaKa: Making it an implicitly unwrapped doesn't necessarily mean you will get a non nil result - If I were in you, I'd limit usage of them to really necessary cases, favoring normal optionals in all other cases.

Comment: @Antonio ,Great! I got what you mean!  Looks like I haven't got the truly usage of `optionals`, I prefer to use `!` than `?`, looks like I have to learn swift deeply

Answer (score 2):

you can map the array

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
let numArray = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map {$0.toInt()!}
```

Comment: Got an error "AnyObject doesn't have a member named toInt()"

Comment: If you know that this `AnyObject` is a string, cast it to String with `as! String`

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6"

func toInt(str: String) -> Int {
    return str.toInt()!
}

let numArray = map(string.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as [String], toInt)
```

Then, `numArray` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 2.0**,

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
let numArray = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map{ Int($0)! }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.0:

```
let string = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
let stringArray = string.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
let intArray = stringArray.flatMap(Int.init)
intArray.max()
```