# Array Maximum Number Finder

Tags: arrays, swift, max

Ok so i have to do this:
Stretch #2: W​rite a loop that iterates through the array named v​alues​and finds the largest number in the array. Place the value into the variable m​aximum. ​

I tired not doing it with a loop, but by :

```
{


    if values[1] > values[0]
    {
      maximum = values[1]
    }
    else if values[2] > values[1]
    {
        maximum = values[2]

    }
    else if values[3] > values[2]
    {
        maximum = values[3]
    }
    else if values[4] > values[3]
    {
        maximum = values[4]
    }


    }
```

That didn't work and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to find max in an Array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036514/correct-way-to-find-max-in-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses an `if - else` chain rather than a loop which is pretty long-winded and annoying for a large amount of items.

You're probably looking for this:

```
var maximum = 0
for aValue in values {
    if aValue > maximum {
       maximum = aValue
    }
}
```

If the array doesn't contain integer values set the variable `maximum` to the appropriate type.